# Event Driven ETL using AWS Lambda, Glue, EventBridge/Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue, aws-event-bridge

I have a lambda which triggers 3-5 glue jobs dynamically depending on input provided by a configuration file. Now, I have to trigger the second lambda only when all the glue jobs triggered by the previous lambda were successful else keep on waiting and if either of them failed fail the entire process and notify.

Comment: Ok. So what is your question/problem?

Comment: I'm assuming your question is "how do I orchestrate Lambda functions and Glue jobs?" and the answer is probably Airflow (MWAA).

Comment: My question is each glue job will enable its own alarm to track the status. How will the second lambda know that all the previous events are successful? One option that I see is to pass the run ids of glue job (**running in parallel) from previous lambda to the second lambda to keep on retrying unless all are successful and then trigger. The other possibility is to dynamically enable the cloudwatchevent to track the status and only trigger the subsequent lambda when all the events were successful. Is second possibility valid and if yes how can we do that?

Comment: I doubt either of the options you suggested are a possibility. I would suggest to look into Step Functions to orchestrate the logic.